# How to iterate through a list of Twitter users using Snscrape?

Tags: python, twitter, scrapy

I trying to retrieve tweets over a list of users, however in the snscrape function this argument is inside quotes, which makes the username to be taken as a fixed input

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
tweets_list1 = []
users_name = [{'username':'@bbcmundo'},{'username':'@nytimes'}]

for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('from:{}').get_items().format(username)):
if i>100:
    break
tweets_list1.append([tweet.date, tweet.id, tweet.content, tweet.url,\
                     tweet.user.username, tweet.user.followersCount,tweet.replyCount,\
                    tweet.retweetCount, tweet.likeCount, tweet.quoteCount, tweet.lang,\
                    tweet.outlinks, tweet.media, tweet.retweetedTweet, tweet.quotedTweet,\
                    tweet.inReplyToTweetId, tweet.inReplyToUser, tweet.mentionedUsers,\
                     tweet.coordinates, tweet.place, tweet.hashtags, tweet.cashtags])
```

As output Python get:

```
`AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'format'
```

This code works fine replacing the curly braces with the username and deleting the .format attribute. If you want replicate this code be sure install snscrape library using:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape.git
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some mistakes that I did writing this code. So, I want to share with all of you just in case you need it and overcome your stuck with this very same problem or a similar one:

First: I changed the users_name format, from a dict to a list items.

Second: I put the format attribute in the right place. Right after text input function

Third: I added a nested loop to scrape each Twitter user account

```
users_name = ['bbcmundo','nytimes']
for n, k in enumerate(users_name):
    for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('from:{}'.format(users_name[n])).get_items()):
    if i>100:
        break
    tweets_list1.append([tweet.date, tweet.id, tweet.content, tweet.url,\
                         tweet.user.username, tweet.user.followersCount,tweet.replyCount,\
                        tweet.retweetCount, tweet.likeCount, tweet.quoteCount, tweet.lang,\
                        tweet.outlinks, tweet.media, tweet.retweetedTweet, tweet.quotedTweet,\
                        tweet.inReplyToTweetId, tweet.inReplyToUser, tweet.mentionedUsers,\
                         tweet.coordinates, tweet.place, tweet.hashtags, tweet.cashtags])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid to make several requests by using more than one from criteria:

```
users = ['bbcmundo','nytimes']
filters = ['since:2022-07-06', 'until:2022-07-07']
from_filters = []
for user in users:
    from_filters.append(f'from:{user}')
filters.append(' OR '.join(from_filters))
tweets = list(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(' '.join(filters)).get_items())
# The argument is 'since:2022-07-06 until:2022-07-07 from:bbcmundo OR from:nytimes'
```